# Singleton class extending a parent class to utilise shared functionality

Tags: java, design-patterns, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

I have a singleton class which extends from an abstract java class. Two singleton classes extend from `ItemImageThreadManager`, the reason for this is to use shared scheduling functionality. A thread is created and passed into the `runThread` method of `ItemImageThreadManager`.

Is this good design?

**Abstract Parent Class**

```
public abstract class ItemImageThreadManager {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void runThread(final Thread runThread){

        try { 
            scheduleTimer(runThread);
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException ise){
            /**
             * When the timer is cancelled (when screen closed) and the images are 
             * removed from memory(in-app resync) and this screen is opened again, 
             * an IllegalStateException will be thrown since the images will need 
             * to be re-downloaded
             * 
             * Solution - create a new timer.
             */
            timer = new Timer();
            scheduleTimer(runThread);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts a new thread. This thread is run in the order is has been added.
     * Since timer runs in it's own thread, this gaurantees that just one thread 
     * will be started at one time....
     * @param thread
     */
    private void scheduleTimer(final Thread thread){

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                thread.start();
                try { 
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, 0);
    }


    public void cancelTimer(){
        timer.cancel();
    }

}
```

**First Extended class**

```
public class ContestantImageThreadManager extends ItemImageThreadManager{

    private static ContestantImageThreadManager ref;

    private ContestantImageThreadManager(){
        super();
    }

    public static ContestantImageThreadManager getSingletonObject()
    {
      if (ref == null){
          ref = new ContestantImageThreadManager();
      }
      return ref;
    }

}
```

**Second Extended class**

```
public class JudgeItemImageThreadManager extends ItemImageThreadManager{

    private static JudgeItemImageThreadManager ref;

    private JudgeItemImageThreadManager(){

    }
    public static JudgeItemImageThreadManager getSingletonObject()
    {
      if (ref == null){
          ref = new JudgeItemImageThreadManager();
      }
      return ref;
    }

}
```

Comment: > Is this good design ?

No . 

 1. Why do you need to two classes with same name ? It would not even compile in same package.
 2. Why do you need Singleton ? I am not as anti-singleton as community in general is these days but certainly there is not obvious reason for this to be a singleton.

You need to give us more  background on problem domain .

Comment: i actually don't see so much of a problem with this assuming you are going to extend this for your domain specific usage. the 2 singletons don't need to be singletons at the moment and runThread method could just have been static. But yes, if you are planning to do more in these classes, I think its fine. make your getSingleton methods synchronized though please.

Comment: I added a differeing singleton class to question, I did'nt realise I copied and pasted the same singleton twice. I take your point about the singleton class though, it's possible I dont need it. Why should my getSingleton methods be synchronized ?

Comment: This was very useful to descibe why a sington need to be synchronized - http://taskinoor.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/singleton_multithreaded/

Comment: If they are not synchronized then it is possible for two threads to call `getSingletonObject()` at the same time and result in two instances of your singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned the `getSingletonObject` should be synchronized. There is a chapter in *Effective Java, Second Edition* about singletons (*Item 3: Enforce the singleton property with a private constructor or an enum type*). It's worth to read. Anyway, try to avoid them, they makes testing really hard.

You use the `Timer` as a *single-threaded executor*. In that case consider using [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29). Furthermore, are you sure that you need to pass `Thread` at all? Wouldn't `Runnable` be enough? `Executor`s can run `Runnable`s without any wrapper class and `Thread.join` call.

Instead of catching `IllegalStateException` in the `runThread` method you should check whether the timer is canceled. You can store this state in a boolean flag. Don't forget to synchronize the variable access. (See *Effective Java, Item 57: Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions*)

`ExecutorService.submit` returns [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) which has a [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method. Maybe it's better for you requirements (instead of `Timer.cancel()`).

If you're not familiar with concurrent code check [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](http://jcip.net/).